# Pubsubhubbub Zend subcriber

Tags: zend-framework, rss, publish-subscribe, websub

I'm reading trough http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.feed.pubsubhubbub.introduction.html
and trying to understand how Pubsubhubbub subscription works. Specifically, what are the credentials I store or how does my hub identify a subscriber. The subscriber has some rss/atom client id, how do I know who the client id is?
Or more precisely, how does the hub know who the subscriber is or how do I tell it who the new subscriber is?

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm for subscribers is actually pretty simple.

1. Fetch existing RSS feed
2. Look for link[@rel="hub"]
3. Subscribe to the hub identified with href of link[@rel="hub"] by sending the feed url (hub.topic) and a webhook to your server (hub.callback)
4. Confirm subscription when the hub sends a verification to the hub.callback
5. Wait for notifications via POST requests on hub.callback with the content in them.

That's it.

There are no credentials involved, there is no "your hub" as a subscriber, no client id...

Comment: Actually what I want is to get how does the server /  the hub identify me as a subscriber

Comment: Read step 3: "a webhook to your server (hub.callback)"